# Can't manage to make Formdata work with PSD files

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, file, post

So I'm trying to use formData to send a file but can't manage to make it work properly.

```
fileButton.addEventListener('change', function(ev)
{
    var file = fileButton.files[0];
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);
    formData.append('ajax', 'fileUpload');
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'index.php', true);
    xhr.onload = function ()
    {
        ...
    };
    xhr.send(formData);
}, false);
```

Index.php checks that $_POST['ajax'] == 'fileUpload' and uploads the file if so.

My code works perfectly on most files but whenever I try to upload a PSD file, my index.php receives an empty $_POST and $_FILES array. I looked up the doc but can't find anything.

Many thanks!

Comment: can it be that the file is too big for your current settings? is your PSD file bigger than the other tests you made?

Comment: I ignored that there was a file size limit expected from the server. I checked my php.ini file and discovered this line 'upload_max_filesize = 2M'. Changing it solved my problem. Thank you very much !

Comment: you're welcome, have a good coding!